# invalid pointer error

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, free

I have some C code embedded inside an R function which keeps sigsegging in the same way, but at different points (through the programs progression - always seems to come from the same function).

Here's the thing - the error I get is;

```
*** glibc detected *** /packages/R/2.15.0/lib64/R/bin/exec/R: munmap_chunk(): 
invalid pointer: 0x0000000014059b20 ***
```

Now this is a pretty standard error (`munmap_chunk()` is part of `free()`, if I recall) - the weird thing is that the error comes from a function which is freeing a set of arrays from within a struct (the program allocs and frees millions of these structs over the course of its running normally).

The function looks like this;

```
multifit_work_t *free_multifit(multifit_work_t *work)
{

  if (work == NULL || work->u==NULL || work->w==NULL || work->v==NULL || work->b==NULL || work->rv1==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Internal array in multifit_work_t object was already NULL\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  // each of the work->* arrays are just an array of doubles of length 1 or more.

  // LOGGING FUNCTIONALITY: Here, prints out the address and values of each 
  // of the arrays

  // free each array first
  free(work->u);
  free(work->w);
  free(work->v);
  free(work->b);
  free(work->rv1);
  free(work);

  // LOGGING FUNCTIONALITY: Here prints an, "Exiting free_multifit()" message

  return NULL;
}
```

So I'm checking each pointer before I free it. I added in logging functionality to output the address and initial value for each of these arrays. Grepping the logfile of the crash which generated the above error for the offending pointer, I get a lot of hits (understandably we're re-using the same memory location after it's freed);

```
$: grep 14059b20 logfile.txt
....
194624) work->b: ADDRESS: [0x14059b20] VALUE: [-5.620804e-02]
194629) work->b: ADDRESS: [0x14059b20] VALUE: [2.759472e+00]
194634) work->b: ADDRESS: [0x14059b20] VALUE: [5.498979e-02]
194684) work->b: ADDRESS: [0x14059b20] VALUE: [9.323869e+07]
194689) work->b: ADDRESS: [0x14059b20] VALUE: [3.016410e+07]
194694) work->b: ADDRESS: [0x14059b20] VALUE: [1.688376e-08]
194699) work->b: ADDRESS: [0x14059b20] VALUE: [1.660441e+00]
.....
```

Operation 194699 is in the last set of values I get before the segfault;

```
Calling free_multifit...
194696) work->u: ADDRESS: [0x1305f7d0] VALUE: [1.350474e+01]
194697) work->w: ADDRESS: [0x92ec810] VALUE: [1.350474e+01]
194698) work->v: ADDRESS: [0x122cc210] VALUE: [5.798884e-09]
194699) work->b: ADDRESS: [0x14059b20] VALUE: [1.660441e+00]
194700) work->rv1: ADDRESS: [0xea37a50] VALUE: [0.000000e+00]
< If it didn't crash in the function we'd see an "Exiting function message" here - so it sigsegs on the freeing of one the the arrays or the work object itself.
[EOF]
```

So, despite checking the pointer is good, and actually pulling a value from it's location (1.66) it seems like when I try and free it all goes wrong.

Any ideas why/how this could happen? Is this a hardware issue? I'm running it on a cluster, if that makes any difference.

**UPDATED 1**

multifit_work_t is created through the following;

```
typedef struct {
  int m,n;
  double *w,*u,*v,*b,*rv1;
} multifit_work_t;


multifit_work_t *alloc_multifit(int m, int n)
{
  multifit_work_t *work=(multifit_work_t *)malloc(sizeof(multifit_work_t));
  if (work==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"failed to allocate multifit_work\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  work->m=m;
  work->n=n;
  work->u=(double *)malloc(n*m*sizeof(double)); /* temporary storage - n x m matrix */
  work->w=(double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double)); /* n vector */
  work->v=(double *)malloc(n*n*sizeof(double)); /* n x n matrix */
  work->b=(double *)malloc(m*sizeof(double)); /* m vector */
  work->rv1=(double *)malloc(n*sizeof(double)); /* temporary storage - n vector */
  if (work->u==NULL || work->w==NULL || work->v==NULL || work->b==NULL || work->rv1==NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr,"failed to allocate multifit_work\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  return work;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

When I run it on my local system the same thing happens, but the error is along the lines of;

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x11e000000, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

Always at a noticeably even memory address.

**UPDATE 3**

Below is the valgrind report

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./execute 
==23072== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==23072== Copyright (C) 2002-2010, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==23072== Using Valgrind-3.6.0.SVN-Debian and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==23072== Command: ./execute
==23072== 
==23072== 
==23072== HEAP SUMMARY:
==23072==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==23072==   total heap usage: 445 allocs, 445 frees, 27,900 bytes allocated
==23072== 
==23072== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==23072== 
==23072== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==23072== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 23 from 8)
```

This is killing me!

Comment: In your `if` statement, you only need to check if `work == NULL`. It doesnt matter if the rest are NULL because `free(NULL)` is safe.

Comment: How do you create the `multifit_work_t` struct?

Comment: You probably have some heap corruption form somewhere earlier in your code, but this is not showing up until you call free(). Try running your code under valgrind.

Comment: Maybe it's a double-free? I think you should null all properties before freeing so that re-running the function with freed memory will detect the null pointer.

Comment: @ Matt - I hadn't realized free(NULL) was safe - thanks


@ Richard - I'll update my answer now to show


@ Paul R I've done a few runs through Valgrind, and not turned up anything so far - any ideas which options would be useful? (There are no memory leaks, I know that much)

Comment: How are you allocating? Are you allocating with new, by chance? Mixing new/free can have disastrous consequences.

Comment: @thejh - sorry, what do you mean? I can't null the array pointers *before* I free them? Nulling them after would be a good idea though (as Matt suggests below)

Comment: @Unni - nope, no mixing and matching, although good idea!

Comment: @Unni, C and C++ are not the same language. If he says it is C code, then there is no `new`.

Comment: @Matt - but there is some C++ elsewhere (which I haven't mentioned) - multifit_work_t is actually only dealt with by the C code, however, which is why I didn't bring it up.

Comment: @Matt : I assumed my stack over flow tag selection would bring only C++ questions to me. Looks like my bad assumption.

Comment: @Alex I mean, you should NULL all properties of a struct before deallocating the struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere, deep, deep, in the code, an input array was only filling a local array a small portion of its (m)allocated size. The code was then calling the uninitialized regions of the array, the values of which looked a lot like the expected input (which is why it took my so long to identify).

In summary - overstepping arrays is bad, but watch out for *understepping* (when initializing) too!

Answer (score 3):

You should get into the habit of setting things to `NULL` after freeing them:

```
free(work->u);
free(work->w);
free(work->v);
free(work->b);
free(work->rv1);
work->u = work->w = work->v = work->b = work->rv1 = NULL;
free(work);
```

Also set work to `NULL` in the function that calls `free_multifit`.

Comment: In this specific case this is not useful. See the function signature : multifit_work_t *free_multifit(multifit_work_t *work). work is pass by value. I think the caller would just assign the return value (which is always NULL) to the variable.

Comment: ^ that's exactly what I'm doing, although equally it's always good to, as Matt says, get in the habit of setting freed pointers to NULL - this is actual code I've inherited.

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing to your arrays, make sure you are not overstepping their bounds. Those pointers are stored in the heap, so we might be seeing pointer corruption from some out of bounds access to your arrays.

> Always at a noticeably even memory address.

Memory is usually byte aligned depending on OS and system, and you are working with 8 byte values (64 bit double precision floats). So you'll probably see a lot of addresses ending at 0x....0, 0x....8, 0x....10, 0x....18, 0x....20 etc.